# Execute statement with DB-API style bind params

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am learning sqlalchemy and want to delete rows that are older than X number of days counting from today.
When I try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import sqlalchemy

db_con_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp...'
connection_url = sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create("mssql+pyodbc",
                                              query={"odbc_connect": db_con_string})
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)

with engine.begin() as sql_conn:
    command = 'delete myschema.Logs where [DateTimeSent] < ?'
    params = ((datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=-90)), )
    sql_conn.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.text(command), params)
```

I get: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries`

My `params` is clearly a tuple so I am thinking it's something to do with datetime. How can I fix this error?

I use SqlAlchemy 2.0.23

Comment: Try `sql_conn.exec_driver_sql(command, params)`

Comment: It worked. How so, is it a crutch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sql_conn.exec_driver_sql(command, params)` worked.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35345922)

Comment: @soulseekah it's confirmation of a comment, not another answer.